# For looping a float in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to for loop a float, and mumu needs to be a float because I'm applying this scalar to list. Mass is another list dependant on a file. I've tried changing mumu to a string, but that doesn't work, is there a rule in python that doesn't allow me to for loop a float value?
Ultimately I want the outfile to look like

Thanks in advance!

```
#Mass mumu(%) -> this is the Statment_change
10 30
20 30
30 30
40 30
.
.
.
etc
```

```
    mumu=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for muon e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
....
....
....
....
....
    with open('OUTFILE1.dat', 'w') as OUTFILE:
        OUTFILE.writelines(Statment_change)
        OUTFILE.writelines('\n')
        for i in range(len(Mass)):
            OUTFILE.writelines(Mass[i])
            OUTFILE.writelines('\t')
            OUTFILE.writelines(mumu*100)
            OUTFILE.writelines('\n')
```

Comment: I believe range only takes ints. but I'm confused how it relates to mums? It seems like you are writing a float to a file which is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
statement_change = "#Mass mumu(%) -> this is the Statment_change"
mumu = 0.3
Mass = [10, 20, 30, 40]
with open('OUTFILE1.dat', 'w') as OUTFILE:
    OUTFILE.writelines(statement_change)
    OUTFILE.writelines('\n')
    lines = [f"{mass}\t{mumu*100}\n" for mass in Mass]
    OUTFILE.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

`writelines()` is expecting an iterable of strings and it will `write()` each of them.

If you pass it a string, then it will iterate over the characters in the string.

When you give it a float (or an int), the iteration fails.  If you want to write something turn it into a string (perhaps with format() or an f-string).

`print()` will take an int/float, but `writelines()` will not.

```
>>> print(3)
3
>>> sys.stdout.writelines(3)
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```